# When unit testing in Python, how can I display my custom message together with the default message when an assert fails?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Consider the following example:

```
import unittest

class MessageExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_with_default_message(self):
        self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges')

    def test_with_custom_message(self):
        self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges', 'You should not compare apples and oranges.')
```

Output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_default_message (assert_message.MessageExampleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges')
AssertionError: 'apples' != 'oranges'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_custom_message (assert_message.MessageExampleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges', 'You should not compare apples and oranges.')
AssertionError: You should not compare apples and oranges.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'd like to see, in the second case, is something like:

```
AssertionError: 'apples' != 'oranges'; You should not compare apples and oranges.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Python 2.7, [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) now provides a [longMessage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage) property that will do this.

In Python 2.7:

```
import unittest

class MessageExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.longMessage = True

    def test_with_custom_message(self):
        self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges', 'You should not compare apples and oranges.')
```

Output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_custom_message (assert_message.MessageExampleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    self.assertEqual('apples', 'oranges', 'You should not compare apples and oranges.')
AssertionError: 'apples' != 'oranges' : You should not compare apples and oranges.

======================================================================
```